# I want to use Command line to install a minimum-required .NET but need to be able to check if it's installed first

Tags: .net, command

I want to use Command line to install a minimum-required .NET but need to be able to check if it's installed first this is my current bat file that i will be using as a login script :

```
    @echo off

SET FileName=%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG
IF EXIST %FileName% GOTO AlreadyInstalled

:installingDotnet
@echo Installing Dotnet Now :
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All

:Installed
@Echo Dotnet frame v2 Installed

GOTO InstallAtera

:AlreadyInstalled
@Echo Dotnet Framework v2 Already Installed

:Installmyprogram
pause

if EXIST "C:\Program Files\afolder\aprogram" GOTO myprogram
if EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\afolder\aprogram" GOTO myprogram

start c:\test\myprogram.exe /Installagent

:myprogramInstalled
@Echo myprogram Installed
pause

:End
```

but verifying the folder does not work and i need to verify the program any help apreciated thx

Answer (score 0):

My Updated Script Working

```
if EXIST "%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\csc.exe" GOTO AlreadyInstalled
:installingDotnet
@echo Installing Dotnet Now :
DISM /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:NetFx3 /All

:Installed
@Echo Dotnet frame v2 Installed

GOTO InstallAtera

:AlreadyInstalled
@Echo Dotnet Framework v2 Already Installed

:Installmyprogram
pause

if EXIST "C:\Program Files\afolder\aprogram" GOTO myprogram
if EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\afolder\aprogram" GOTO myprogram

start c:\test\myprogram.exe /Installagent

:myprogramInstalled
@Echo myprogram Installed
pause

:End
```